# Entity Framework Query Cache bloat on SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I currently have an issue in that there are thousands of plans created on the DB for 1 style of EF query.

The query itself is parametrized, but the parameter name keeps changing and hence the text is different, and so results in a fresh new compile for each query hitting my DB server.

So the query looks like this.

```
(@p__linq__100687 int)SELECT   [Extent1].[MyColumn] From MyTable [Extent1]
Where Column1 = @p__linq__100687
```

and the next one looks like this

```
(@p__linq__100688 int)SELECT   [Extent1].[MyColumn] From MyTable [Extent1]
    Where Column1 = @p__linq__100688
```

What I would like EF to do is

```
(@p__linq__1 int)SELECT   [Extent1].[MyColumn] From MyTable [Extent1]
    Where Column1 = @p__linq__1
```

And then keep reusing the query above instead of incrementing and then being 
forced to create a new plan.

So when I trawl through the plan cache on the DB I get a total of 7GB of plans which have only been used once.

I am a DBA and need to figure out what to tell the Vendor Devs since they are adamant that this is the correct way to implement EF as per MS.

I have searched google and asked a couple of dev friends around the construction of the code in the background but the answer still eludes.

Comment: Consider [alternatives to EF](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) (optionally after spending another few days troubleshooting :))

Comment: It is a Vendor application and they have introduced EF into getting data from one particular table. My guess is that the method which creates the sql is being instantiated for each new parameter being used instead of reusing the object. But that is a DBA guess as I am not a .Net Dev.

Comment: The overhead for compiling a query is pretty low, usually below 25ms. Unless you expect hundreds of queries per second it's not a problem. The developers will be unable to make EF work in a way that looks good to a DBA, hehe :)

Comment: Total sum of space used to store execution plans for the same query family on the dbserver = 7GB and this is only when EF has been added into selecting from one particular table. I am very skeptical that this is how EF is supposed to work.

Comment: I think that EF is supposed to create one object which stores the way to query the database, but this is being instantiated persistently. That sounds like a bug. Also,  if a query plan is not even cached, its reuse opportunity is zero. Such a plan will be compiled every time it is executed, resulting in poor performance. -> from MSDN https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966425.aspx

Comment: You can ask SQL Server to [parameterize queries for you](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  That option is intended to help with deranged libraries (like EF) that you can't easily control.

Comment: Thanks Andomar for the suggestion. Forced parameterization will stop sql from using filtered indexes if it is being compared to a literal value, i.e. createindex blah on blah (soso) where statusid = 2, since the value of 2 in a query will be given a parameter value before the plan is created. That being said, I have serious doubts that the people who designed EF intended for this to happen on a properly implemented application.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some tests using VS 2017 and EF 6 and had no problem with this, even trying some bad c# codes.

I tried this:

```
        AdventureWorks2016Entities ctx = new AdventureWorks2016Entities();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            var query = (from x in ctx.bigProduct.AsNoTracking()
                         where x.ReorderPoint == i
                         select x);
            var result = query.ToList();
        }
```

and this :

```
        for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            AdventureWorks2016Entities ctx = new AdventureWorks2016Entities();
            var query = (from x in ctx.bigProduct.AsNoTracking()
                         where x.ReorderPoint == i
                         select x);
            var result = query.ToList();
        }
```

The first code block is re-creating the query in each iteration and the 2nd code block is also re-creating the context in each iteration. None of these options created the plan cache bloat you are suffering.

What's the EF version your application is using ?

However, I found this problem with the decimal type in EF. I just posted a question about this, you can find it here - [How to avoid plan cache bloat using queries in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151376/how-to-avoid-plan-cache-bloat-using-queries-in-entity-framework)