# How to avoid plan cache bloat using queries in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I found a related question about entity framework here - [Why is Entity Framework passing a parameter as DECIMAL(5,0) for a column defined with NUMERIC(19)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333529/why-is-entity-framework-passing-a-parameter-as-decimal5-0-for-a-column-defined/24333880#24333880) - however the answer explains this as regular behavior of entity framework.

In a LinqToEntities query, such as this one:

```
        var query = (from x in ctx.bigProduct.AsNoTracking()
                     where x.ListPrice == v
                     select x);
```

Entity framework translates the parameter "v" using different precisions. In my attempts, sometimes translates as decimal(2,2) and sometimes as decimal(5,2), for example.

The problem is that this difference in the parameter type results in a recompilation of the query that could be reused from the query plan cache, also creating a plan cache bloat.

How to avoid this difference in parameter types?

Comment: Adhoc query setting will help from the SQL side but does not answer the Q ( hence it being a comment ☺ )

Comment: Optimize for Ad Hoc Workloads = True. Server wide option.